# Code stuck looping while when numeric value entered

Tags: c++

Hey my code is stuck on looping my while when I input numeric letters, it just floods my output with "Invalid Input, please try again." It's just a simple menu.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You're not checking whether input suceeded. Something that you must always do. `if(!(cin >> userOption)) { /* invalid input, do not use userOption */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever enter anything "invalid", such that reading from cin will cause an error, you have to call `cin.clear()` to be able to read further input, otherwise the stream in operator will just return immediately.

Typically, when reading user input, you check the state of cin and exit or do some error handling when it is invalid. In addition, on a failed input attempt, the characters that caused the error will still be sitting in cin, and need to be ignored (e.g., up to the next newline):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int userOption;
    while(1) {
        while(!(std::cin >> userOption)) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << userOption << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just for the record, std::numeric_limits comes from the header [limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits)

Comment: Hey thanks for this, how can I also add it so there is a limit on the numeric input maximum value of 12.

Comment: @Hayde You could either add another check after the while loop, or add the check into the existing while loop (`while(!(cin >> userOption) || userOption>12) {`)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason only every 2nd case is working, and the others are saying invalid.

Comment: @Hayde I added a complete code snippet that compiles and runs fine. You are probably looping somewhere you're not expecting, hitting an extra std::cin. Try to have a single std::cin as in the code above, rather than a separate std::cin when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line of code,

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

When you are entering a single number, you don't have to ignore any other character. So simply remove the above line of code to correct your program.

Comment: That depends on what you want: if you want the input `1iosdf` to be parsed as 1, with the rest being ignored, then ignoring the rest of the line is the way to go.